# Unhandled exception when running sample code in opencv 3.1

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to run a sample code called stitching_detailed.cpp from opencv 3.1 (By the way, I can build stitching_detailed.cpp successfully). However, it showed the following error:

`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDE7011F28 in stitching_detailed.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000935AF3B820.`

But when I run another sample code called stitching.cpp from the same folder, it built and run successfully.

I'm using visual studio 2015. The sample codes come with opencv 3.1 in the following directory: `C:\opencv\sources\samples\cpp`.

Others have suggested it is because of wrong environment variable path or something similar but I believe my paths are ok since the other sample code runs fine.

**Edit 1:**
The link to the stitching_detailed.cpp code is [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp). When I try to run it, it points to `return Ptr<T>(new T());` of the following part of code in [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp):

```
Ptr<T> makePtr()
{
    return Ptr<T>(new T());
}
```

I'm new to coding and was hoping that it's a problem with my settings rather than the code assuming that it's well tested and maintained.

**Edit 2**

When I ran the program in the command line it showed this error:

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (OpenCV was built without 
SURF support) in cv: : detail: :SurfFeaturesFinder: :SurfFeaturesFinder, file C: \bui 
ldslave64\win64 amdoc1\master PackS1ave-win64-vc14-shared\opencv\modu1es\stitchi 
ng\src\matchers . cpp, line 361
```

It seems that for this opencv version the feature is not installed (it is in a separate opencv_contrib module). Will try it.

Comment: most of us are not really familiar with stitching_detailed.cpp so you might consider adding some code to your question and some details about how you tried to debug it before raising the question

Comment: "I'm using visual studio 2015" - That includes a  debugger that is arguably  one of (if not *the*) finest available for the Windows platform. Catching that exception and examining your surroundings the moment the wheels fall off will probably be at least a little helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because I didn't install the separate opencv_contrib module which has a feature (SURF feature detection) that is used in the program. It ran with no errors after compiling opencv with the opencv_contrib module using cmake.

For more details, I followed instructions on compiling it through this website:
https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/